# Retrieve StorageFile with the help of path from Local Folder

Tags: window, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I am making Windows 8.1 Universal App and want to retrieve file,
 `(local -> folder -> sub Folder -> file)` which is stored in Local Folder.

One way is open Local Folder, then open folder, then open sub folder, then file.
But If I know the path, can I simply open the file?

(Like in Windows Phone 8, `store.OpenFile()`)

Is there an API which would return Storage File when passed path?

Example: `GetStorageFile("local/folder/subFolder/file")` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.getfilefromapplicationuriasync.aspx) and pass in a URI such as `ms-appdata:///local/folder/subfolder/file.txt`. This is preferred over `GetFileFromPathAsync` (@Parad1s3's suggestion) since it is relative to your data folder and won't change if the location of the app changes (eg, on a phone the user can move to or from the SD card).

Answer (score 0):

```
string path = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder + "\\" + "YourFolder" + "\\" + "YourSubfolder" + "\\yourfile.xml";
StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync(path);
```

Hope this helps.